# SSIS Excel file name to date?

Tags: excel, ssis

hopefully someone can help me with this.

I have an SSIS package which is fed by an Excel file, I have created a variable which places the excel file name in a derived column (ctp_finalv_250688.xlsx)

I was wondering how I would go about extracting the "250688" part of the file name and placing that in another derived column?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I have written an expression to suit your need.

My variable `varFileName` is string having `ctp_finalv_250688.xlsx` as input.

`SUBSTRING( @[User::varFileName] ,LEN( @[User::varFileName] ) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::varFileName] ),"_",1) + 2,FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::varFileName] ),"_",1)-6)`

Catch this expression in another variable like this sample :

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is static naming convention. If yes, this should work using Derived column.

```
LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::varFileName],11),6)
```

Also, you can replace same column in order to avoid adding an additional Column.